# whats this: _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!text"

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

This is a game called word relay (this is only in korea and idk is this right)
ex: sugar -> rice -> extra -> arms -> ......

but it makes an error like this

```
  File "d:\Jiho\우와! 파이선\끝말잇기\끝말잇기 창에서.py", line 93, in ai       
    txt1.insert(END, words2[rdm]+' => ') # here is the problem
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\peoplecom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3809, in insert
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'insert', index, chars) + args)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!text"
```

source codes below:

```
'''
바꿀것

1. 라벨에다가 출력
2. ai 코드 수정
3. 입력 다 없애고 라벨에다가 추가
4. 라벨이 꽉 차면 어떻게 할지
'''


# 전처리
import random
import hgtk # hangul toolkit
from tkinter import *

file = open('딕셔너리.txt', 'r', encoding = 'UTF8')
words = file.read().split('\n') # 단어장 리스트로 읽어오기
file2 = open('dict.txt', 'r', encoding = 'UTF8')
words_for_guest = file2.read().split('\n') # 사람을 위한 단어장 읽어오기
used_words = [] # 이미 쓴 단어들 모으는 리스트
last = '' # 두음법칙 x
last2 = '' # 두음법칙 ㅇ
last3 = '' # 두음법칙 ㄴ
speaker = 'guest' # guest = 사용자, ai = 상대
end = False

# 함수 만들기

# 두음법칙 ㅇ으로 적용하기
def makelast2(last):
    dcp = hgtk.text.decompose(last)
    dcp = dcp.replace(dcp[0], 'ㅇ', 1)
    return hgtk.text.compose(dcp)

# 두음법칙 ㄴ으로 적용하기
def makelast3(last):
    dcp = hgtk.text.decompose(last)
    dcp = dcp.replace(dcp[0], 'ㄴ', 1)
    return hgtk.text.compose(dcp)

# 사용자가 단어 입력하기
def guest():
    global words, speaker, last, last2, last3, end, lbl2, txt1, ent1
    a = ent1.get()
    if a.encode().isalpha() == True: # encode 안하면 한글도 영어로 취급
        lbl2.config(text = '한글로 다시 해')
    elif len(a) < 2:
        lbl2.config(text = '두 글자 이상으로 다시 해')
    elif a == '졌다':
        lbl2.config(text = '그러면 내가 이겼다!')
        end = True
        return
    elif last != '': # 처음글자가 맞는지 판별
        if a[0] != last and a[0] != last2 and a[0] != last3:
            lbl2.config(text = '첫 글자가 틀렸어. 다시 해')
    elif a in used_words:
        lbl2.config(text = '이미 쓴 단어야. 다시 해')
    elif a not in words_for_guest:
        lbl2.config(text = '그런 명사는 없어. 다시 해')
    else:
        txt1.insert(END, a+' => ')
        last = a[-1]
        if last >= '나' and last < '다':
            last2 = makelast2(last)
            last3 = makelast3(last)
        elif last >= '라' and last < '마':
            last2 = makelast2(last)
            last3 = makelast3(last)
        else:
            last2 = last
            last3 = last
        words_for_guest.remove(a)
        if a not in used_words:
            used_words.append(a)
        speaker = 'AI'
        return

# 컴퓨터가 대답하기
def ai():
    global words, speaker, last, last2, last3, end, lbl2, txt1
    words2 = []
    for i in words: 
        if len(i) < 2:
            continue
        elif i[0] == last or i[0] == last2 or i[0] == last3:
            words2.append(i)                
    if len(words2) == 0:
        lbl2.config(text = '내가 졌다!')
        end = True
        return
    else:
        rdm = random.randint(0, len(words2)-1)
        txt1.insert(END, words2[rdm]+' => ') # here is the problem
        last = words2[rdm][-1]
        if last >= '나' and last < '다':
            last2 = makelast2(last)
            last3 = makelast3(last)
        elif last >= '라' and last < '마':
            last2 = makelast2(last)
            last3 = makelast3(last)    
        else:
            last2 = last
            last3 = last
        if words2[rdm] not in used_words:
            used_words.append(words2[rdm])
        speaker = "guest"
        return

# 창 만들기
win = Tk()
win.geometry("700x600")
win.title("끝말잇기")

lbl1 = Label(win, text = '끝말잇기 게임', width = 15, height = 3, font = ('굴림', 20))
lbl1.pack()

txt1 = Text(win, width = 20, height = 10, font = ('굴림', 20), relief = 'ridge')
txt1.pack()

여백1 = Label(win, text = '', width = 1, height = 1)
여백1.pack()

ent1 = Entry(win, width = 20, font = ('굴림', 20))
ent1.pack()

여백2 = Label(win, text = '', width = 1, height = 1)
여백2.pack()

btn1 = Button(win, width = 5, text = '확인', font = ('굴림', 15), command = guest)
btn1.pack()

여백3 = Label(win, text = '', width = 1, height = 1)
여백3.pack()

lbl2 = Label(win, text = '단어를 입력하세요', width = 30, font = ('굴림', 15),
              relief = 'ridge')
lbl2.pack()

# 게임 시작
print('\'졌다\' 라고 하면 기권할 수 있어')
print('너부터 해')
while not end:
    if speaker == "AI":
        ai()
    win.mainloop()
```

What should I do to solve this?

I tested the function `.insert(something)`, but only this is not working. I searched much of the question about this bug, but I couldn't solve this.

Comment: This error is raised when you try to `insert` into a text box that has been destroyed. Instead of `speaker = "AI"` call `ai()` directly. That will remove the need for the `while` loop you have at the end which is probably why you are getting confused.